# unable to communicate securely with peer requested domian name does not match the server's certificate

Tags: devops

while uploading artifact from 1 nexus to another nexus we are getting issue "unable to communicate securely with peer requested domain name does not match the server's certificate"

I am expecting upload the artifact from one nexus to another nexus